# Adding an etag/version to assets with brunch

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, cdn, bower, brunch

To compile my static web project I use **Brunch**. In order to serve it via a CDN without invalidating upon deploy I'd like to add an etag to my assets, e.g. `my-app-12345.css` instead of `my-app.css`.

Adding the etag to the file isn't the problem, but wiring it up in the index.html is a bit harder.

Is there a module that does this already? Or how could I achieve this otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [digest-brunch](https://github.com/mutewinter/digest-brunch), does exactly what I need!